# How can we add attachment to default mail Application Using NSWorkSpace in cocoa Mac OSX application

Tags: swift, macos, email, cocoa, nsworkspace

I am using NSWorkspace to set TO, CC, BCC , SUBJECT and body text in default mail application through my application. How can i add attachments using NSWrokSpace?
Is there any way to attach files in the default mail app using NSWorkSpace?
I have tried using NSSharingService but problem with NSSharingService is that you cannot set CC and BCC email addresses in the default application Email Compose.
Is there any way to add CC, and BCC recipients using NSSharingSerivce ??
or is there any way to add attachments in mail using NSWorkSpace??
My code to open and set TO, CC and BCC is here

```
 NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(NSURL.init(string:"mai‌​lto:(self.txtTo.‌​stringValue)"+"?subj‌​ect=YourSubject"+"&c‌​c="+self.txtCC.strin‌​gValue+"&bcc="+self.‌​txtBcc.stringValue)!‌​)
```

And Using NSSharingService i can set only recipients as TO

```
 service!.recipients = [self.txtTo.stringValue]
 service!.subject = "Subject"
```

thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `NSSharingService` has the method `performWithItems`, which takes an array of the things you want to share.

It appears you can create a sharing service of type `NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail` and then attach a message body and a file to attach.

I've never used `NSSharingService` before, so the above is based on some Googling and reading the docs. (And I mostly work in iOS these days so my Mac OS is getting a little stale.)

Check out this link:

http://cutecoder.org/featured/programmatically-sending-rich-text-mail-attachment-mac/

Comment: Thanks Duncan! but problem with NSShairngService is that you cannot add "CC" and "BCC" Recipients, while you can only set "To" Recipients.and i need both attachments and as well as need to set CC, and BCC recipients.