# Open new Mail with attachment via Cocoa in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, email, cocoa, attachment

I am searching for a way to open a new Mail and attach a file as an attachment vis Swift on macOS.
There is a way to do this on iOS but I as far as I can see there seems no way on macOS for this.
Thanks for any hints!

Comment: There is a way via AppleScript, either directly using `NSAppleScript` or with an AppleScriptObjC bridge, however the latter needs a little help form Objective-C

Comment: Similar question: [How can we add attachment to default mail Application Using NSWorkSpace in cocoa Mac OSX application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778223/how-can-we-add-attachment-to-default-mail-application-using-nsworkspace-in-cocoa/40097370#40097370)